# php contact form output issues

Tags: php, contact-form

So I'm trying to make a contact me form for a website and this is my first time making one of these forms. My issue is that for some odd reason my button is not sending anything and the button doesn't want to work.

**This is the input form**

```
<div>
        <form id="contact-us" method="post" action="contact-form-handler.php"> 
            <input name="name" type="text"class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" required>
            <br>
            <input name="phone" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phonenumber no symbols or dashes"required>
            <br>
            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" required>
            <br>
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="write us a message" rows="4" required></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="form-control-submit" value="SEND">
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Here is my handler.**

```
    <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_from = 'website.com';
    $email_subject = 'New message from customer';
    $email_body = "name:  .$name. \n". 
                    "email: .$visitor_mail.\n".
                    "phone: .$phone. \n".
                    "message: .$message. \n";
    $to= "email@gmail.com";
    $headers= $email_from.;
    $headers .= $visitor_email.;

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working but if anyone could help me that would be amazing.

Comment: update this line - $headers= $email_from.;  To $headers= $email_from;  You have dot (.) after $email_form and  $visitor_email variables that causing error on page to sending email.

Comment: "My issue is that for some odd reason my button is not sending anything and the button doesn't want to work. "  . This issue occurs when any html tag not closed properly in html page. check all tags are closed properly. and other if you miss > symbol in any html page tags . this issue will occur.

Comment: HTML tags are looking ok, you can check for css class ( form-control-submit ) added on submit button, not sure if any js event working on this class, so just remove this class once and try to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <form id="contact-us" method="post" action="contact-form-handler.php">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" required>
        <br>
        <input name="phone" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phonenumber no symbols or dashes" required>
        <br>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" required>
        <br>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="write us a message" rows="4" required></textarea>
        <br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="form-control-submit" value="SEND">
    </form>
</div>
```

Handler

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_from = 'website.com';
    $email_subject = 'New message from customer';
    $email_body = "name:  {$name} \n" .
        "email: {$visitor_email}\n" .
        "phone: {$phone} \n" .
        "message: {$message} \n";
    $to = "email@gmail.com";

    $headers = $email_from;
    $headers .= $visitor_email;

    $res = mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
    header("Location: index.html");
}
```

I found a few errors in your code:

```
$headers= $email_from.; // syntax error - need to remove dot before ;
$headers .= $visitor_email.; // syntax error - need to remove dot before; same here
```

In your email body, you used `$visitor_mail` variable, but your is `$visitor_email`
Also, I've added the name tag to your form and added an additional validation condition.

Please try to use this solution, I hope it will help you. This solution is working fine on my side